# Fix this regex that detects, reorders and replaces dates within a string with items from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, replace

This is the function in charge of transforming the dates to obtain the desired output (at the end there are the 3 outputs for each of the 3 inputs that are given as an example of operation). The problem with this function is that since it depends on the string it detects, I still haven't found convenient ways to replace the names of the months with the associated numeric values through the dictionary.

```py
import re, datetime

def month_standarization(match):
    input_text_substring = match.group()

    input_text_substring = re.sub(r"este mes", str(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m')), input_text_substring)
    input_text_substring = re.sub(r"(?:el mes que viene|el siguiente mes|el mes siguiente)", str( int(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m') ) + 1), input_text_substring)
    input_text_substring = re.sub(r"(?:el mes pasado|el pasado mes|el anterior año|el mes anterior)", str( int(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m') ) - 1), input_text_substring)

    input_text_substring = re.sub(r"este año", str(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y')), input_text_substring)
    input_text_substring = re.sub(r"(?:el año que viene|el siguiente año|el año siguiente)", str( int(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y') ) + 1), input_text_substring)
    input_text_substring = re.sub(r"(?:el año pasado|el pasado año|el anterior año|el año anterior)", str( int(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y') ) - 1), input_text_substring)


    #to transform ordinal numbers into cardinal numbers
    #  example: '1º' --> '1'  or  '10º' --> '10'
    input_text_substring = re.sub("(\d{1,2})[\s|]*º", r"\1", input_text_substring)


    #put '0' in front a day number only if it is one number and not two
    #  example: '1' --> '01'  or  '10' --> '10'
    input_text_substring 

    #replace the name of the month with the associated number in the 'es_month_dict' dictionary
    #  example: 'enero' --> '01'  or  'noviembre' --> '11'
    #input_text_substring =

    return input_text_substring
```

Here are some examples covering the kind of possible cases the regex should be able to deal with (basically to simulate the possible inputs that this program could receive)

```py
#Input examples:
input_text = "ya es 1º de mayo, recuerda que el dia 1 del mes de mayo es el dia del trabajador, y que este mes es de fiesta"  #example 1
input_text = "el dia 02 de este mes es un dia espacial, recuerda que desde el 14 de septiembre hasta el dia 30 de este mes esta la feria, y hay que preparar 4 eventos"  #example 2
input_text = "desde el 14 de septiembre hasta el 30 de octubre del 2021, los negocios estuvieron cerrados pero desde el 1º de enero de este año todos abrieron"  #example 3
```

And here are the dictionaries used for the replacements, plus the function is called from within a replacement regex. The problem with this regex is that it doesn't detect examples correctly.

```py
es_month_dict = { "enero":"01", "febrero":"02", "marzo":"03", "abril":"04", "mayo":"05", "junio":"06", "julio":"07", "agosto":"08","septiembre":"09", "octubre":"10", "noviembre":"11", "diciembre":"12" }
quantity_days_associated_to_month_num = { "01":"01_to_31", "02":"01_to_28", "03":"01_to_31", "04":"01_to_30", "05":"01_to_31", "06":"01_to_30", "07":"1_to_31", "08":"1_to_31", "09":"1_to_30", "10":"1_to_31", "11":"1_to_30", "12":"1_to_31" }


identificate_day = r"(\d{1,2})[\s|]*º"
identificate_month = r"(?:este mes|el mes que viene|el siguiente mes|el mes siguiente|el mes pasado|el pasado mes|el anterior año|el mes anterior|enero|febrero|marzo|abril|mayo|junio|julio|agosto|septiembre|octubre|noviembre|diciembre|(\d{1,2}))"
identificate_year = r"(?:\d*|este año|el año que viene|el siguiente año|el año siguiente|el año pasado|el pasado año|el anterior año|el año anterior)" #should be a numeric value with a minimum of one digit and a maximum of infinite digits as long as there are no spaces between them

identification_regex = r"[\s|]*(?:del |de |)[\s|]*(?:dia|)[\s|]*" + identificate_day + "[\s|]*(?:dia|)" + r"[\s|]*(?:del |de )[\s|]*(?:mes|)[\s|]*" + identificate_month + r"[\s|]*(?:del |de )[\s|]*" + "(?:año|)[\s|]*" + identificate_year


#to transform ordinal numbers into cardinal numbers
input_text = re.sub(identification_regex, month_standarization, input_text)

print(repr(input_text)) #output
```

Rules in case any of the **3 parts of the date (Year-Month-Day)** is missing:

- If the year is not known, the current one is assumed `datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y')`
- If consecutive days are passed and only the month is indicated on the second day, both dates are taken with the same month(the second), for example:  `input_text = "desde el 13 hasta el 15 de noviembre"`
  become into:
  `output = "desde 2022-11-13 hasta 2022-11-15"`
  . In these cases, `"hasta"` or `" al "` appears in the middle.
- If 2 consecutive months pass and the year is not indicated in the first date, the year of the second of them is assumed, for example:  `input_text = "desde el 13 de noviembre hasta el 15 de noviembre de 2025"`
  become into:
  `output = "desde 2025-11-13 hasta 2025-11-15"`
  . In these cases, `"hasta"` or `" al "` appears in the middle.
- If you have the month and/or the year but you do not have the day, an interval of all the days of that month is placed based on the dictionary called `quantity_days_associated_to_number_month`, for example: `input_text = "desde noviembre hasta diciembre de 2025"`
  become into:
  `output = "desde el 2025-11-(01_to_30) hasta 2025-12-(01_to_30)"`

For the **3 input examples**, this is the correct output:

```py
"ya es 2022-05-01, recuerda que el 2022-05-01 es el dia del trabajador, y que 2022-05-(01_to_31) es de fiesta" #for example 1
"el dia 2022-10-02 es un dia espacial, recuerda que desde el 2022-09-14 hasta el 2022-10-30 esta la feria, y hay que preparar 4 eventos" #for example 2
"desde el 2021-09-14 hasta el 2021-10-30, los negocios estuvieron cerrados pero desde el 2022-01-01 todos abrieron" #for example 3
```

What should I change in my code and in my regex to be able to obtain the original string with the standardized dates in the order **(Year-Month-Day)** and fulfilling the criteria mentioned to obtain those outputs?

Comment: Please bear in mind `"\1"` != `r"\1"`. The `"\1"` is a char with octal number `1` and `r"\1"` is a backreference to Group 1 value.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right there I have modified that detail so that when entering the function, I manage to interpret the \1 as a replacement and not as a simple string. Even so, in principle the problem that is blocking me is the identification regex to be able to extract the correct substrings and send them to the modifier function `month_standarization()`.